# Why does the C compiler give these results in 05 and 07 case?

Tags: c, pointers

I have trouble understanding the 05 and 07 case. Why does it print out 12A, and 1?

```
    struct s {short s; char c; int i;};
    struct s s1={0x333231, 0501, -2};
    printf("01:%o\n", sizeof(s1));
    printf("02:%x\n", s1.s);
    printf("03:%x\n", s1.c);
    printf("04:%x\n", s1.i);
    printf("05:%s\n", (char*)&s1); //12A
    printf("06:%d\n", sizeof((char*)&s1));
    printf("07:%c\n", *(char*)&s1); //1
```

Comment: what about to give the definition of *s* ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not 123 ? (on a little endian machine)

Comment: You're improperly using `%s`.

Comment: because `0501 - 256 = 65 /* = 'A' */`, but it's UB in the first place

Comment: Added the line. Positive it's not 123.

Comment: `(short)0x333231 == 0x3231`, `(char)0501 == 'A'`, padding (probably `0`), `(int)-2`

Comment: In ASCII '1' is 0x31, '2' is '0x32 and 'A' is 0x41 (65)

Comment: Understood 05 case, what about 07. Thank you all

Comment: case 07 --- first char of case 05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obviously all depends on the compiler but in your case visibly the values are truncated like that :

```
struct s s1={0x3231, 65, -2};
```

> ```
> printf("05:%s\n", (char*)&s1); //12A
> ```

having `short` on 16 bits, `char` on 8 bits, and you visibly are in little endian so the bytes from `&s` are : 0x31, 0x32 and 65 corresponding in ASCII to '1' then '2' then 'A'

The 0 finishing the 'string' is coming from a padding and you have 'chance' to have 0 in it

> ```
> printf("07:%c\n", *(char*)&s1); //1
> ```

for the same reason the first character of the 'string' is '1'

All of that is compiler dependent